# Search string in code in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am looking for a particular div in the Shopify Liquid files of a large-ish site I am new to and that I did not build. However, I have to check the files one by one to find if the div is there, which is unefficient. The PHPStorm editor has the ctrl+shift+F option to search the file arborescence for a specific string in any file. Does Shopify have an equivalent, and what is it?

Not to be confused with:

- Adding a search bar on a Shopify site
- Searching Shopify store admin (I need to look at the Liquid code, not the store)

Tried already:

- Googled 'shopify equivalent of phpstorm ctrl+shift+F'
- Googled 'shopify keyboard shortcuts'
- Googled 'shopify find in path'
- Googled 'shopify search code'

Found no relevant result.

Comment: Just export and download the whole theme into a file system. Then "find in files" with the editor of your choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid I have never seen such feature on the Shopify Editor. What I usually do, however, if you're not working with the theme locally already is:

1. Export the theme via `Download Theme File`
2. Download the .zip and extract it.
3. Open it with your favourite Editor (I personally use Sublime)
4. Use `Find in Folder` or your text-editor equivalent to search for the string on the whole theme.

Sadly, there's no better workflow as of now. You should consider however, [setting up your theme locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803486/how-to-develop-shopify-themes-locally/38814778#38814778) so you can take advantage of version control and a more organized workflow that could help maintenance and new updates on that site.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked!! Found div in one second!!! Thank you so much @Juan Ferreras.

Answer (score -1):

2 options:

1) download locally (many devs work locally now using theme kit or another tool)
unzip theme and do a search either with text editor or with file manager

2) you can also use screaming frog to scan sites in detail - may be more useful though in cases where the div is not actually technically in theme but say in a metafield or added by an app.