# Shopify Theme Kit on local machine

Tags: shopify

Seriously, how do you get [this](http://themekit.cat/) to work?

I've installed the `theme` in the root of my OSX 10.11.16 then and to my `bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="~/.themekit:$PATH"
```

Restarted my terminal and `theme` gives me some commands so I assume all is ok. No?

In the directory I want to work in, I've created a `config.yml` file:

```
development:
  theme_id: 123456
  store: demo.myshopify.com
  password: f821e54-SOMEPASSWORD-4ed1b82ed1
  bucket_size: 40
  refill_rate: 2
  concurrency: 2
```

The password I got from the Authentication section of my private app. The command `theme download` gives me this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
[ThemeKit - Shopify Theme Utilities v0.4.2 Author: Chris Saunders]
----------------------------------------------------------------

2016/08/19 15:12:35 Server responded with HTTP 403; please check your credentials.
```

The `password` is correct. 100% correct. Is there an update to this Utility? How do you get this to work? Have a missed a step?

Comment: New Private Apps need to specify exactly what they will be using. Can you check that you have enough permissions? Can you check you've given `Theme templates and theme assets` Write Access?

Comment: You have no idea, no idea how much thanks I give to you! Thank you very much! I havent seen any information with what you've given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm making an answer out of the comment just in case someone else runs into this issue.*

There's been an update on Permissions that now discriminate the kind of access you allow for every Private App.

[image]

It's required for ThemeKit or [any other way you're pushing updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803486/how-to-develop-shopify-themes-locally?rq=1) to your Shopify Theme to count with **Read and write** on `Theme templates and theme assets`.

Shopify Docs on the matter are pretty slim, but also self explanatory. [Here's](https://help.shopify.com/api/guides/authentication/oauth#scopes) a breakdown of the different scopes.