# Shopify Local Installation

Tags: php, shopify, local, development-environment

I'm completely new to Shopify development.

I want to know if there any way to set up a**Shopify Store Locally** for learning purposes, or any other way to set up **Shopify Development Environment**

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to develop Shopify themes locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803486/how-to-develop-shopify-themes-locally)

Comment: Actually I want to setup Shopify Store as like we install WordPress. Completely local environment.

Comment: @SahilBuddhadev you can't install Shopify locally. If you want to create a local environment for your apps, that's a different story, you can, so the app can use the Shopify API, also webhooks and so on but the Shopify Core is always in the cloud.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can.

You can use the following: https://shopify.github.io/themekit/

Or you can use https://shopify.github.io/slate/ ( which uses themekit in the background )

Themekit support Windows and Mac so you are good in both OS.

You only need the following things:

- setup Themekit correctly following the guide here https://shopify.github.io/themekit/#installation
- create a [Private App](https://help.shopify.com/manual/apps/private-apps) in your Shopify store
- create a local config file with the following command `theme configure -p YOUR_PRIVATE_APP_PASSWORD -s YOUR_STORE_NAME.myshopify.com -t THEME_ID`
- after you create your `config.yml` file, you do `theme download` which will download your theme
- and once your download is complete you start `theme watch` and everything you save in the directory will be pushed automatically to your theme

And that's all. Good luck!

PS:

You need to have a development store! Create an account here as a developer: https://developers.shopify.com/ and you will be able to create multiply development stores in your dashboard without the need to pay.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: no, you can't.

It's not possible to install/run Shopify locally to your own server like Wordpress.

Shopify is software-as-a-service [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) which means that Shopify owns the servers and installs/updates/maintains the software that ultimately powers your store.

With WooCommerce, you have access to all the code that runs the store.  But with  Shopify you don't.  You can only customize the theme and not see the underlying code that powers your store or customize it.

As others have stated, if you just need to develop a theme, there are options that simplify the process of not being able to run locally.  Though it should be noted this is still **not offline development** as themekit/etc. all require a shopify store and communicate/upload your changes as you go.  It's just a proxy, and not actually running locally.

Answer (score 0):

**No you can't install shopify locally**

Shopify has it's own server. You can install a shopify theme locally, develop the theme and push it to shopify backend

Comment: From Review: Hi, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

afaik the new way to do shopify development is using Shopify CLI
https://shopify.dev/themes/tools/cli

> Shopify CLI replaces Theme Kit for most Shopify theme development tasks. You should use Shopify CLI if you're working on Online Store 2.0 themes. You should use Theme Kit instead of Shopify CLI only if you're working on older themes or you have Theme Kit integrated into your existing theme development workflows.